# C-r in term-mode doesn't access reverse-i-search

Tags: term

I find that in term-char-mode with bash, C-r doesn't activate the
shell's reverse-i-search function.  How can I do that?

PS.
Apologies: I was using **multi-term** mode and had somehow convinced myself
the problem was derived from term mode.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue in Emacs without init file (`emacs -q`). Have you tried that as well? If the issue doesn't pop up in such situation, it's likely that your init file is the culprit. Another possible cause would be your shell setup.

Comment: Re your update: you mean the problem only occurs when using `multi-term`?

Comment: @npostavs, yes.  it also happened in term just now, but only after i presumably did something.  i have no idea what.  after a restart it worked as expected again.

Comment: @Toothrot what when it fails to reverse-i-search, what happens instead?